# transition animation not working from recycled view to detail screen

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, fragment, transition

I'm having trouble using a simple transition animation where I have a recycled view with several items and upon pressing an item, I want the text on an item to move up to its new location in the details screen opened.
I created a github project with a sample of what I meant

https://github.com/guylis/android_projects/tree/master/testAnimation/app/src/main/java/guy/testanimation

FragmentA has the recycled view with the items
Fragment B has a details screen showing the item

- When pressing the item in fragmentA, the adapter passes the item to fragmentB that opens a details screen
- I defined a unique transition name for each view displayed in fragmentA
- When opening the details screen I first postponed the animation, created the rellevant move animation and only after onCreate when setting the transition name to the rellevant textview, I continued the animation
- The animation isn't working, the text simple "jumps" from one place to another instead of moving towards it

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing like this you can consider using pairs.

```
   holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext /*your context from main activity*/, Destination.class);

            Pair[] pairs = new Pair[3]; /* careful about the number and how many element you want to animate*/
            pairs[0]= new Pair<View, String>(holder.X /*item to animate to next activity*/, "transitionX" /* name of transition animation that you have to set on your xml file of the item*/);
            pairs[1]= new Pair<View, String>(holder.Y, "transitionY");
            pairs[2]= new Pair<View, String>(holder.Z, "transitionZ");

            ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) mContext, pairs);
            // start the activity
            mContext.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
        }
    }); 


 class CourseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView X;
        ImageView Y;
        LinearLayout Z; /* you can animate layout as well*/ 

        private CourseViewHolder(View itemView) {
             super(itemView);         
             X= itemView.findViewById(R.id.x);
             Y=itemView.findViewById(R.id.y);
             Z=itemView.findViewById(R.id.z);
        }
 }
```

itemView.xml file

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/x"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:transitionName="transitionX"/>

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/x"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:transitionName="transitionY"/>

   <LinearLayout    <!-- you can animate Layout to another object -->
        android:id="@+id/Z"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:transitionName="transitionZ">
        ----------------------
        --------------------
   </LinearLayout>
```

destinationclass.xml file

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/x_will_transit_to"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:transitionName="transitionX"/> <!-- The name of transition must be the same as java file and both of the element from xml file -->

   <!-- You can also animate one type of View to another when transition take place -->

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/y_will_transit_to"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:transitionName="transitionY"/>

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/z__will_transit_to"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:transitionName="transitionZ"/>
```

it does not matter whether you are transiting from recyclerview to fragment or what else.. you just need to set the animation inside the action or where onClick takes place. give the transition same name in layout of both files among which the transition will take place. and finally, in case, check in your emulator or mobile device you are testing the app should have all animation scale at least 1x (in developer option). Hope it helps even though it might not be the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, I believe that's not the problem, I uploaded a sample project with the code to the original answer to make it more clear.
Thank you